# Does the surface finish of the strings on a musical instrument impact the timbre?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, applied-mechanics

Suppose we are testing out different  *unwound* strings on a piano.

Each of the tested strings is made of the same material, has the same length, same diameter, density, etc., the only difference being the surface finish (highly polished, matte, rough like sandpaper, etc.)

How does this impact the timbre of the string?

Comment: how would you measure the difference? ... two "identical" strings do not sound the same at some level

Comment: This is a theoretical question that should not take practical concerns into consideration. For the sake of this question, the only difference between the strings is the surface roughness. I am not looking for a measurement, more so an understanding of how surface roughness impacts the harmonic content of the vibrating string

Comment: @Flywheel Obviously the depth of the roughness makes a difference, as does the uniformity of said depth along the string length.  I don't think you can get to an analytic result.  You'll just have to test each string's elasticity as a function of frequency (and tension) and make a lookup table or graph.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the timbre, by definition, is the profile made by a soundwave passing throught a medium of propagation on a amplitude vs time graph, we can assume that the surface roughness is acting as a final barrier on the solid and transmitting interface between the solid and gasous media.

Being it the final barrier on the solid-solid propagation of soundwaves (phonons  on the crystal lattice) its shape (represented by Ra and Rz and another roughness values as a mean) will influenche the shape in which these soundwaves will reflect, diffrate and interfere with eachother, meaning it will influence the final waveform of the sound on the solid-solid proapagation medium.

Being it the interface between the solid and gasous phases, it will influence how the energy of said phonons will propagate to the newly found medium, but given that this influence is rather small compared to the overall movement of the string, it can be ignored without major problems.

I'll be a little daring and say it has a negligible, if not null, influence on the final sound you hear, given that the overall motion of the string that causes the wave you hear.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt to answer may prove to be little more than a brain cell lost in action but timbre, I believe, has more to do with environmental resonance than materiał causing it.

The harmonics is an interaction within a material rather than its surface texture. Having said that, sound is the waves of gaseous pressure against our eardrums. I think the clue is in this.

A matt finish may produce greater air friction but measuring that is going to be pointless because it will be insignificant in the grand scale of piano strings. Maybe the bass note strings would benefit from being matt and highly polished strings for treble clarity.

With higher friction comes greater resistance to movement which means the sustained vibration time may be lower between identical strings base their surface finish.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it will have little effect on the sound. Most of the volume is transmitted by the soundboard rather than the strings themselves. Witness the difference in volume between a solid-body electric guitar played unamplified and an acoustic guitar with the same strings played in the same manner.